# Create table with stored function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I have a query for create table like below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BAJUL;
CREATE TABLE BAJUL AS (
SELECT dt_trx, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt_trx DESC) AS row_number
FROM stock_trx_idx
WHERE dt_trx BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-28'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC);
```

How able to create above table with stored function in Postgresql?
I tried with below script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (dt1 DATE, dt2 DATE)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblq;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblq AS(
    SELECT dt_trx, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt_trx DESC) AS row_number
    FROM stock_trx
    WHERE dt_trx BETWEEN dt1 AND dt2
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
   )' );

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but when I try to execute SF like below

```
SELECT my_function ('2017-01-01', '2017-02-28');
```

I got error --> ERROR: column "dt1" does not exist

Would like to seek your help.

Thanks & rgds,
Bayu

Comment: You do not need either `format()` function nor `EXECUTE` statement or this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
format('CREATE ... WHERE dt_trx BETWEEN %L AND %L ...', dt1, dt2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You error is obvious. In the SELECT statement,

```
SELECT dt_trx, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt_trx DESC) AS row_number
    FROM stock_trx
    WHERE dt_trx BETWEEN dt1 AND dt2
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The dt1 column doesn't exist. You didn't tell him you wanted to use your variable. Try concatenate your string with your variables.

By the way, you can drop your ORDER BY if your creating a table with that statement.

Comment: Hi Arkhena, Yes I would use dt1 as my variable, so then when I execute I will do like below

`SELECT my_function ('2017-01-01', '2017-02-28');`

My question, How to pass that variable into dt1 & dt2